# How to get status for bluetooth privacy setting in iOS6

Tags: ios6, core-bluetooth

Question about iOS6 peripheral bluetooth connection.

in info.plist if I add UIBackgroundModes bluetooth-peripheral, at app launch it asks permission for first time.

[image: "appname" would like to make data available to nearby bluetooth devices even when you're not using the app]
"appname" would like to make data available to nearby bluetooth devices even when you're not using the app

if I deny (don't allow) the request, setting - privacy - Bluetooth Sharing - "Appname" turned to "OFF";

I set to listen CBPeripheralManagerDelegate to see if I can, but it always return "ON" even I deny the request. (that's also make sense because it is "on" before it goes to background)

```
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral{
NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
NSLog(@"%@",[peripheral description]);
NSString *state = nil;
switch (peripheral.state) {
    case CBPeripheralManagerStateResetting:
        state = @"resetting"; break;
    case CBPeripheralManagerStateUnsupported:
        state = @"unsupported"; break;
    case CBPeripheralManagerStateUnauthorized:
        state = @"unauthorized"; break;
    case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOff:
        state = @"off"; break;
    case CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn:
        state = @"on"; break;
    default:
        state = @"unknown"; break;
}
NSLog(@"peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:%@ to %@ (%d)", peripheral, state, peripheral.state);

}
```

I see the CBPeripheralManagerStateUnauthorized looks like it shows denied status but I can't get this status even I denied request.

Question is:
"Is there any way I can find out user denied background access request?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CBPeripheralManager` has an `authorizationStatus` property which reports this information back. ([Apple documentation link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheralManager_Class/Reference/CBPeripheralManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CBPeripheralManager/authorizationStatus)).

`+ (CBPeripheralAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus`

"Returns the app’s authorization status for sharing data while in the background state. A value indicating whether the app is authorized to share data using Bluetooth services while in the background. For a list of the possible values, see “Peripheral Manager Authorization Status.”"

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for iOS 6 era, but it finally has been implemented on iOS 7.